# How to call wcf service Asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

if wcf service is design the below way then please guide me how call `Add()` function `Asynchronously` from client side. thanks

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAddTwoNumbers
{
    // If the asynchronous method pair
    // appears on the client channel, the client can call 
    // them asynchronously to prevent blocking.
    [OperationContract (AsyncPattern=true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginAdd(int a, int b, AsyncCallback cb, AsyncState s);

    [OperationContract]
    int EndAdd(IAsyncResult r);

    // This is a synchronous version of the BeginAdd/EndAdd pair.
    // It appears in the client channel code by default. 
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int a, int b);
   }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best way is to [convert the APM pattern into the Task pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx?Redirected=true), using [`Task.Factory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```cs
public static class WcfExt
{
    public static Task<int> AddAsync(this IAddTwoNumbers service, int a, int b)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
             (asyncCallback, asyncState) =>
                 service.BeginAdd(a, b, asyncCallback, asyncState),
             (asyncResult) =>
                 service.EndAdd(asyncResult), null);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IAddTwoNumbers service = CreateWcfClientProxy();
int result = await service.AddAsync(a, b);
```

Comment: i am familiar with APM but not with TASK but like to know u used here asyncCallback function reference but when u r calling AddAsync() then u are not sending asyncCallback function reference....why?

Comment: @Mou, `asyncCallback` will be supplied internally by the Framework implementation of `FromAsync`, when it calls my lambda.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an async wire communication pattern, and WFC is no exception. Going async *across the wire* requires fundamental changes in your service and your contract. Specifically your contract has to be a bidirectional contract and the 'end' must be pushed from the service to the client, along with the result. In other words, across the wire the 'async' becomes a callback.