# Use of IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle for Concurrency

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronization

I have a .Net Proxy class that has several web service methods, each method has its Begin*Operation* and End*Operation*. I am experiencing web service requests that are getting stuck and has no response.

I am thinking of making use of the AsyncWaitHandle property of the return value of the Begin*Operation* method. I just dont know exactly where to put it.

Here is my code:

```
public activateResponse activateServiceReq([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("activateServiceReq", Namespace = "http://AAA/BBB")] activateServiceReq activateServiceReq1)
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("activateServiceReq", new object[] { activateServiceReq1});
    return ((activateServiceReqResponse)(results[0]));
}
```

//The Begin operation where I will use the `AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne`

```
public System.IAsyncResult BeginactivateServiceReq(activateServiceReq activateServiceReq1, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
{
    IAsyncResult result = this.BeginInvoke("activateServiceReq", new object[] { activateServiceReq1}, callback, asyncState);
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    return result;
}

/// <remarks/>
public activateServiceReqResponse EndactivateServiceReq(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    object[] results = this.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
    return ((activateServiceReqResponse)(results[0]));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call wcf service Asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481210/how-to-call-wcf-service-asynchronously)

Comment: My example involves a plain web service and not a WCF one. I just want to ask for a suggestion or any efficient way to impose a wait before the asynchronous operation completes.

Comment: it's not clear, you have an XML web service proxy and you want to modify the generated code of it, i.e., `BeginactivateServiceReq` in this case? Where is the problem: calling the web service from the client side, or accepting calls on the server-side?

Comment: Yes. The BeginactivateServiceReq and EndactivateServiceReq are auto generated methods using WSDL.exe. I want to use the WaitOne() method of BeginInvoke result so that any incoming thread will be blocked until the asynchronous operation completes. Is it possible?

Comment: This would be wrong. You should not modify the proxy code. Use the `Task.Factory.FromAsync` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481210/how-to-call-wcf-service-asynchronously) to call your proxy, it's not specific to WCF. Just substitute your own `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX` methods.

Comment: But the web service calls come from an another application. I mean, the call directly invokes the web service method.

Comment: It's getting more confusing to me. Are you responsible for the web service code (server-side), or for the application code (client-side)?

Comment: Im developing the client side where the actual web service call takes place.

Comment: *But the web service calls come from an another application* ... *Im developing the client side where the actual web service call takes place*... It's getting even more confusing now. Which application do you have the control over?

Comment: There is a control system that sends the request (written using a proprietary language). The request is processes by a .Net Proxy where the request parameters are converted, then calls an actual web service. This is where I am involved.