# fastest and optimized way to load async result

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, wcf, optimization

What is the fastest and optimized way to load asynchronous results from various sources in web services?

```
Dictionary<string, int> readySources = GetReadyHotelSources(member);

        eventFlag = new AutoResetEvent[readySources.Count];
        int maxTimeOut = 0;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> activeSource in readySources)
        {
            maxTimeOut = (int)activeSource.Value > maxTimeOut ? (int)activeSource.Value : maxTimeOut;
            i++;
        }
        int j = 0;            
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, WaitCallback> deThread in listOfThreads)
        {
            if (readySources.ContainsKey(deThread.Key))
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(deThread.Value, j);
                eventFlag[j] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                j++;                    
            }
        }

        if (j != 0)
        {
            if (!WaitHandle.WaitAll(eventFlag, new TimeSpan(0, 0, maxTimeOut), true))
            {
                //TODO: audit which thread is timed out                
            }
        }          
        // combined sources    
        result = CombineHotelSources();
```

Now i want to move this code in async mode in web services.

Comment: If those various sources are CPU-bound calculational tasks, there's no point in doing them in parallel on the server side. That might greatly impact the scalability. If those sources are IO/network-bound, this may help: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: Yes, these are external sources over the network which we are hitting.

Answer (score 0):

Use asynchronous `Task`-based API and [async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info), as described here:

[Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Avoid wrapping a synchronous call with `await Task.Run()`, here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21793240/1768303) of what I mean. Normally you don't need to create new threads or explicitly use pool threads on the server side. You can call your WCF services asynchronously with `Task.Factory.FromAsync`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21481210/1768303).