# Asynchronous socket calls freezing UI Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I have been working on a client to server chat messenger and I have run into some issues regarding asynchronous calls. I have been trying, with no success, to fix them for a while.

The issue is with the client, there is no problem connecting to the server but once the first 'BeginSend' method is called the whole client stops responding.(It doesn't stop 100% it occasionally responds but after a ridiculous response time of 30 seconds+). The rest of the calls operate fine but the UI wont respond. The server responds fine as well.

Here is the code, I have commented HERE where the client first freezes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Client_GUI_Design_Test
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Socket clientSocket;
        public string strName;
        public byte[] byteData = new byte[1024];
        public List<String> contacts = new List<String>();
        public Boolean needUpdate = true;
       // public Panel globalPanel;
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public struct Contact
        {
            public string strName;
        }


        public int num1 = 0;
        public void addContact(String contactName, String message, int status, int imageNum)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(this.Size.Width.ToString());
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
            panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
            if (num1 >= panel1.Size.Height - 47)
            {
                panel1.Size = new Size(257, 514);
                this.Size = new Size(277, this.Size.Height);
                panel1.AutoScroll = true;
                panel1.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
                panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
                panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
            }
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
            //Contact Panel
            Panel contactPanel = new Panel();
            contactPanel.Size = new Size(249, 47);
            contactPanel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            //Name Label
            Label name = new Label();
            //Font
            float size = 12.00f;
            name.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", size, FontStyle.Bold);
            //Location
            name.Location = new Point(29, 3);
            //Size
            name.Size = new Size(112, 20);
            name.Text = contactName;
            //Events
            #region
            name.MouseEnter += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            };
            name.MouseLeave += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            };
            #endregion
            contactPanel.Controls.Add(name);

            //Image Box
            PictureBox image = new PictureBox();
            //Image
            image.Image = imageList1.Images[imageNum];
            //Size
            image.Size = new Size(56, 42);
            //Location
            image.Location = new Point(187, 4);
            //Events
            #region
            image.MouseEnter += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            };
            image.MouseLeave += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            };
            #endregion
            contactPanel.Controls.Add(image);

            //Status
            PictureBox statusPic = new PictureBox();
            //Image
            statusPic.Image = imageList2.Images[status];
            //Size
            statusPic.Size = new Size(20, 20);
            //Location
            statusPic.Location = new Point(3, 3);
            //Events
            #region
            statusPic.MouseEnter += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            };
            statusPic.MouseLeave += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            };
            #endregion
            contactPanel.Controls.Add(statusPic);

            //Message Label
            Label messageL = new Label();
            //Font
            float sizem = 11.25f;
            messageL.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", sizem, FontStyle.Bold);
            messageL.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            //Location
            messageL.Location = new Point(29, 23);
            //Size
            messageL.Size = new Size(153, 18);
            //Text
            messageL.Text = message;
            //Events
            #region
            messageL.MouseEnter += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            };
            messageL.MouseLeave += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            };
            messageL.MouseHover += delegate
            {
                ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
                tip.Tag = messageL.Text;
                tip.Show(messageL.Text, messageL, 1, 1, 750);
            };
            #endregion

            contactPanel.Controls.Add(messageL);

            contactPanel.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(contactPanel_Paint);
            {


            };
            contactPanel.MouseEnter += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            };
            contactPanel.MouseLeave += delegate
            {
                contactPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            };
            contactPanel.Location = new Point(0, num1);
            //globalPanel = contactPanel;
            //panel1.Controls.Add(contactPanel);
            addPanel(contactPanel);
            num1 += 47;


        }

        public delegate void UpdatePanelCallBack(Panel panel);
        private void addPanel(Panel panel)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                object[] pList = { panel };
                panel1.BeginInvoke(new
                   UpdatePanelCallBack(OnUpdatePanel), pList);
            }

            else
            {
                OnUpdatePanel(panel);
            }
        }

        private void OnUpdatePanel(Panel panel)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Add(panel);
        }

        VisualStyleRenderer renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Normal);
        void contactPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            renderer.DrawEdge(e.Graphics, panel1.ClientRectangle,
                Edges.Top,
                EdgeStyle.Bump, EdgeEffects.Flat);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                //IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(txtServerIP.Text);
                //Server is listening on port 43594
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 43594);

                //Connect to the server
                clientSocket.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SGSclient", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        }

        private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndSend(ar);
                //clientSocket.EndSend(ar);
               //strName = textBox2.Text;
               // DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SGSclient", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket.EndConnect(ar);

                //We are connected so we login into the server
                Data msgToSend = new Data();
                msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.Login;
                msgToSend.strName = textBox2.Text;
                msgToSend.strMessage = null;

                byte[] b = msgToSend.ToByte();

                //Send the message to the server
                //HERE - Starts freezing the UI thread, continues to do background operations
                clientSocket.BeginSend(b, 0, b.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), clientSocket);

                clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData,
                                       0,
                                       byteData.Length,
                                       SocketFlags.None,
                                       new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                       clientSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SGSclient", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            panel4.Visible = false;
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        public void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

                Data msgReceived = new Data(byteData);
                //Accordingly process the message received
                switch (msgReceived.cmdCommand)
                {
                    case Command.Login:
                        //lstChatters.Items.Add(msgReceived.strName);
                        break;

                    case Command.Logout:
                        //lstChatters.Items.Remove(msgReceived.strName);
                        break;

                    case Command.Message:
                        break;

                    case Command.List:
                        MessageBox.Show(msgReceived.strName);
                        //contacts.Add(msgReceived.strName);
                        needUpdate = true;
                        //lstChatters.Items.AddRange(msgReceived.strMessage.Split('*'));
                        //lstChatters.Items.RemoveAt(lstChatters.Items.Count - 1);
                        //txtChatBox.Text += "<<<" + strName + " has joined the room>>>\r\n";

                        break;
                }

                byteData = new byte[1024];

                clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData,
                                          0,
                                          byteData.Length,
                                          SocketFlags.None,
                                          new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                          clientSocket);

            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            { }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SGSclientTCP: " + strName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            //backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if(needUpdate){

                }
            }
        }


        private void Login_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("");
            foreach (string s in contacts)
            {
                addContact(s, "Random Message", 0, 1);
                needUpdate = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fixed the problem in the other classes, however still having issues in OnReceive (Might help to faster identify the issue)

```
public void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndReceive(ar);

                Data msgReceived = new Data(byteData);
                //Accordingly process the message received
                switch (msgReceived.cmdCommand)
                {
                    case Command.Login:
                        //lstChatters.Items.Add(msgReceived.strName);
                        break;

                    case Command.Logout:
                        //lstChatters.Items.Remove(msgReceived.strName);
                        break;

                    case Command.Message:
                        break;

                    case Command.List:
                        MessageBox.Show(msgReceived.strName);
                        //contacts.Add(msgReceived.strName);
                        needUpdate = true;
                        //lstChatters.Items.AddRange(msgReceived.strMessage.Split('*'));
                        //lstChatters.Items.RemoveAt(lstChatters.Items.Count - 1);
                        //txtChatBox.Text += "<<<" + strName + " has joined the room>>>\r\n";

                        break;
                }

                byteData = new byte[1024];

               /* client.BeginReceive(byteData,
                                          0,
                                          byteData.Length,
                                          SocketFlags.None,
                                          new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                          client);*/

            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            { }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SGSclientTCP: " + strName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

I know it is a lot of code, I am sorry but this is my last option I am completely stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try this clientSocket.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), clientSocket); and inside OnConnect use the socket from ar.AsyncState same as in OnSend. You are accessing clientSocket from different thread.

Comment: @MihaiHantea After following you advice I was able to fix most of the methods apart from onReceive. I am still running into the same problem there.

Comment: You mean is still freezing when you call client.EndReceive(ar) ?

Comment: @MihaiHantea yes, and by trial and error I have determined it freezes as soon as it calls: "client.BeginReceive(byteData,
                                       0,
                                       byteData.Length,
                                       SocketFlags.None,
                                       new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                       client);
From the OnConnect Method

Comment: @SimonTaylor, are you limited to C# 4.0 / VS2010? Otherwise, you should be using `Task`-based socket API and `async`/`await`. It would reduce your code to a fraction of its size, and will make it a lot more simple and less error-prone.

Comment: @Noseratio I am able to use C# 4.5 / VS2012 could you perhaps send me a link so I can have a look at how they work, perhaps and example or another question?

Comment: @SimonTaylor, some links: [1](http://bsmadhu.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/simplify-asynchronous-programming-with-c-5-asyncawait/), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22033127/1768303), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22222531/1768303).

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks, I will look into it but does it require .net 5.0 because I am not sure I can target that :(

Comment: @SimonTaylor, it requires .NET 4.5 and VS2012+ (i.e .C# 5.0).

Comment: @Noseratio oh sorry misread it, I should be able to use it. I will take a look, see what I can do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing clientSocket from different thread.

Inside `button3_Click` call `BeginConnect` passing your socket like this:

```
//Connect to the server
clientSocket.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), clientSocket);
```

Inside `OnReceive` get the socket from AsyncState (passed here when called `BeginConnect`):

```
Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
client.EndReceive(ar);
```

From msdn [EndConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endconnect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`EndConnect is a blocking method that completes the asynchronous remote host connection request started in the BeginConnect method`

`Before calling BeginConnect, you need to create a callback method that implements the AsyncCallback delegate. This callback method executes in a separate thread and is called by the system after BeginConnect returns. The callback method must accept the IAsyncResult returned by the BeginConnect method as a parameter.`

EDIT:

As i can see in your code, your are using `byteData` buffer which is declared as class field and accessed from another thread when `BeginReceive` is trying to access it. Check the `Asynchronous Server Socket Example` to see how you can handle the reading part.

You can look at this example on msdn [Socket Code Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Asynchronous Server Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Asynchronous Client Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant but I can't see anything in my code that deviates from your solutions. My code runs, without freezing, fine as long as I dont call any BeginReceive methods, hence I feel the issue may reside in the OnReceive methods. Also are the manual event handlers, which are present in the msdn examples, necessary they feel as I feel they defeat the purpose of A-Synchronicity. Thank you so much for your help so far :)

Comment: I updated the answer. When you use that byteData buffer you are doing same thing as before, accessing resources owned by the UI thread from another thread. Try using  a similar class as in their example StateObject.

Comment: Thanks your solution works, however I am having trouble reading data the same way as that shown in the example.
I create a new instance of StateObject and pass it as the state to OnReceive

I then create a new instance of StateObject from ar.AsyncState however it still freezes as if I had accessed resources from the main thread, if you could help it would be so Amazing :)

Comment: Can you post another question for the BeginReceive, OnReceive with the relevant code to see how it looks now? I guess you are missing something.

Comment: Sorry I was away from my computer temporarily, here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655111/asynchronous-sockets-blocking-ui-thread

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Ok, I will have a look.