# Calling a web service using the new async/await syntax

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asynchronous, async-await

Can anyone point me to an example of calling a web service (not WCF) from C# using the new async/await syntax?
Something like this:

```
public async Task<List<Widgets>> GetWidgetsAsync()
{
    var proxy = new Service1();
    var response = await proxy.GetWidgetsAsync();
    return response.Result;
}
```

Comment: Well what's generating the proxy for you? You've said you're not using WCF, but not what you *are* using.

Comment: This is an asmx web service. I'm using VS2012's Add Service Reference > Advanced > Add Web Reference

Comment: The implementation of the web service is irrelevant to the client. Why don't you had a service reference instead?

Comment: @PauloMorgado There are numerous services that are incompatible with the modern Service Reference implementation, like eTapestry's API http://www.4loopdev.com/etapestry-asp.net-example.html

Answer (score 3):

For a WCF service, when you add a reference and generate a proxy, there are options to generate either `Task`-based async methods or APM-based `BeginXXX/EndXXX` async methods.

I'm not sure about referencing the old-style XML Web service (asmx), but I think at least the second option should be there for it. In which case, you may wrap `BeginXXX/EndXXX` with `Task.Factory.FromAsync`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21498956/1768303).

Answer (score 0):

There's a good explanation here:

[Interop with Other Asynchronous Patterns and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types)

In specific it seems this expample fits your (and my) needs:

```
 public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(Uri url)
 {
      var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
      var wc = new WebClient();
      wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) =>
          {
              if (e.Error != null) 
                 tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
              else if (e.Cancelled) 
                 tcs.TrySetCanceled();
              else 
                 tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
          };
      wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);
      return tcs.Task;
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is the official documentation for the Await and Async [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx). I followed their example, but I did not try with a Web service.

Comment: Question was specifically about Web Services, which don't provide async for you. You have to wrap them yourself if you want Task/async/await.