# How to convert a delegate function into an inline await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading a file asynchronously to Azure blob storage using a standard function, however the only method I have available to use, uses a delegate to pass control to a second function.  But I need a return value from the first function (preferably using await).

How can I await the result and therefore return the value in the first function?  Can I await the delegate function?  I want to return blob.uri

Here's the code:

```
      private Uri uploadImageFileToContainer(byte[] fileContent, string containerName, string blobName)
    {
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = myAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExist();
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        // see: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/windows-azure-blockblob-putblock-method/ for details            

        HashSet<string> blocklist = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (FileBlock block in GetFileBlocks(fileContent))
        {
            blockBlob.PutBlock(
                block.Id,
                new MemoryStream(block.Content, true),
                null
                );
            blocklist.Add(block.Id);
        }
         **AsyncCallback UploadCompleted = new AsyncCallback(OnUploadCompleted);
         blockBlob.BeginPutBlockList(blocklist, OnUploadCompleted, blockBlob);**


    }

    private void   OnUploadCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)result.AsyncState;
        blob.SetMetadata();
        blob.EndPutBlockList(result );
    }
```

Comment: For `BeginXXX/EndXXX` APM callback pattern, you can use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` and `await` the task it returns, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21498956/1768303).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all `async/await` methods, you need to begin by making your method `async` and returning a `Task`. Then use `FromAsync` to wrap the old async pattern in a Task. Something like this ought to work.

```
private async Task<Uri> uploadImageFileToContainer(byte[] fileContent, string containerName, string blobName)
{ 
    ...
    await Task.Factory.FromAsync<IEnumerable<string>>(
        blockBlob.BeginPutBlockList, blockBlob.EndPutBlockList, blockList, blockBlob);
    blob.SetMetadata();
    return blob.Uri;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the latest versions of Azure Storage Client Library, all APIs have a corresponding Async overload that returns a Task. For example, please refer to [CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblocklistasync.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WindowsAzure.Storager version 4.2.1

Instead of:

```
AsyncCallback UploadCompleted = new AsyncCallback(OnUploadCompleted);
blockBlob.BeginPutBlockList(blocklist, OnUploadCompleted, blockBlob);
```

I can:

```
await blockBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blocklist);
blockBlob.SetMetadata();
blockBlob.EndPutBlockList(result);
```